# Render simple two row table in TWIG template - Symfony2

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-2.4

This question is terrible basic, but I tried to find out the answer both on the Symfony documentation as well as in forums and tutorials but everyone does it differently and no solution seems to work with my code.

I just need to render two columns of data with a TWIG template. It has to show the messages sent from a contact form where the only fields are the email of the sender and the body of the message.

The Entity for this is named as Enquiry.

The member function is as follows:

```
public function showAction()
{
    $enquiry = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyWebSiteBundle:Enquiry')->findAll()

    if (!$enquiry) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No elements found'
        );
    }

    return $this->render('MyWebSiteBundle:Page:admin.html.twig', array('object' => $enquiry));
}
```

And the part to the template which is supposed to show the result looks as follows:

```
        {% for item in object %}
            {{ item.email }} - {{ item.body }} <br>
        {% else %}
            <h2>Aoutch ! No data !</h2>
        {% endfor %}
```

Thank you very much in advance I will be much relieve to find the answer to this.

Comment: Attention: you have written double $ in the parameters that you are passing to your template ( `$$enquiry` ). Have you already dump `$enquiry` variable ? Could you share your dump ? Your code seems to be ok except for the parameters passed to the template.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, the problem was related to the Entity creation, now it works.

The code shown above works perfectly well (Symfony 2.4)